# How can I filter on null with fql?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

```
select name, birthday 
from user 
where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
    and birthday != null;
```

results in

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#602) NULL is not a member of the user table.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 602
  }
}
```

Can I filter out the null values somehow?

Comment: Oops, I thought your code was SQL. Sorry!

Comment: well you cant, you need to make your code flexible enough so that it detects the null's and just skips them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use str* functions...  Simply use 'where *field*' to exclude null values, or 'where not *field*' to exclude non-null values.  For this particular example:

select name, birthday 
from user 
where birthday
and uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())

Answer (score 0):

This should pull out all the nulls it works on getting common letters in the months of the year

`SELECT name, birthday, email, uid FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND (strpos(lower(birthday),"a") >=0 OR strpos(lower(birthday),"e") >=0 OR strpos(lower(birthday),"u") >=0) ORDER BY birthday_date`